# Trying to Create a Return on Chained Methods with NSubstitute and Getting Null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have one line of code in a method that I need to set a return value for to make sure the overall method's unit test passes whether the new line of code passes or fails (it's in a try-catch block).

Here's the (names-altered) line of code:

```
await _serviceFactory.GetUserService().Method1(user, new List<Item>(), true)
```

`GetUserService()` returns an instance of `UserService` class.
`Method1` returns a `Task<Variable>` (it's in a try-catch block so in unit testing I'm having it return either `Task<Variable>` or an `Exception` to make sure overall method works for either case).
The test setup for the above includes the following:

```
//mock to use for _serviceFactory
_mockServiceFactory = Substitute.For<IServiceFactory>();
_mockUserService= Substitute.For<UserService>
_mockServiceFactory.GetUserService().Returns(_mockUserService);
```

These are set in a method that gets called in `Setup()`

I have the following in the `Arrange` section of my test method:
If the test case is saying `Method1` should return an exception, the following:

```
_mockUserService.Method1(user, new List<Item>(), true)
            .Returns(Task.FromException<Variable>(new Exception()));
```

else

```
_mockUserService.Method1(user, new List<Item>(), true)
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new Variable()));
```

When debugging the test, the line of code I'm trying to add and set the method's return value returns null, regardless of whether I set the return value to `Task<Variable>` or an `Exception` in the test itself.

So

```
await _serviceFactory.GetUserService().Method1(user, new List<Item>(), true)
```

is returning **null** when running the test. What am I missing in my setup? I figure it's that when `Method1`'s return value is set, it is separate from when the `GetUserService()` return value is set and they're disconnected. I'm spinning wheels and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Method1`, the second parameter is `new List<Item>()`. When I'm setting up what this method should return with the given parameters in the test, it's getting a `new List<Item>()`. However, when the test runs and `Method1` is actually hit, a new `List<Item>()` is generated and doesn't match the  `List<Item>` setup in the test, hence why it's returning null.

The fix was to change `new List<Item>()` as the second parameter to `Arg.Any<List<Item>>()`

Also, for anyone who caught my first setup that is trying to return an exception, that should use `.Throws` and not `.Returns`.